# How to limit the content of a message on index page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new at Rails. I want to know how to display content in form of "some content..." on the index page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`truncate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate) helper like this:

```
<%= truncate(message, :length => 12) %>
```

Comment: wonderful and sweet way to truncate your data, thanks a lot Mischa